# How to implement auto publish to user's facebook timeline just like Instagram?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, client-server, facebook-ios-sdk

I am building a social app that user can post into my app. Data stores in our own server and display to iOS native app.   I am trying to make the post that user publish to our app to user's facebook timeline.    I know that I can post data to my server and then let my app use graph api to publish data directly to facebook timeline.   But that will be double post and make the transfer data double which I think might not be a good practise.

So I want to post it to my server first and let server do the rest. Just like shown in facebook docuement
"Auth on Client, API Calls from Server"
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

[image: Auth on Client, API Calls from Server]

But I wonder if this is the case for my app. Because as shown in the diagram "API calls are forwarded to server as a proxy for Facebook API calls" .  And this is not the case for my app. Because the API calls will be initiated in the server side when the user use client to post new data.

I wonder how most app implement this.For example ,app such as Instagram and other social app.   I am not sure if I do just as I explain will violate any facebook term of usage .

TIA,
Kong

Answer (score 0):

your case perfectly suits the model in the chart.
You said "I am trying to make the post that user publish to our app to user's facebook timeline". I'm assuming you are attempting to mimic instagram since you mentioned it. Let's say user A 'logged-in-by-facebook' on your app and made a post within your app, the app posted to your server (and push back to other users of your Android/iPhone app so they can see, right?). At this time, there's nothing to post to the user's timeline, the scope is in your app only. If the user chooses to post to his Facebook timeline, you take that very same post (which is now saved on your server) and made the call to Graph API and post there, so his friends on FB just see the FB version, not the one within your app.

Comment: Yes, I want to mimic Instagram. But Instagram auto-post that photo to user's timeline in facebook . So it is pre-autorized before and then the app doesn't need to notify user when posting to timeline . Am I understanding this correctly? Does this kind of request need "offline_access" permission ?

Comment: In your case if you only trigger the FB post immediately when the user posts in your app, you dont need off_line access. I.e, you just need short live token. That being said, those are still two separate posts (although the text is the same)